# How to enable auto-generating main method when creating console application in VS Code in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, program-entry-point

In .NET 6.0, the [`Main` method is simplified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) by removing and main method. Now it's possible to start writing code directly without it.

But I want to enable it back and don't want to write it by hand every time when new project is created. I'm using VS Code, but I couldn't find any straight way to accomplish this.

Is there any option for this or any shortcut like writing "prop" to create property quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your cursor on the code that it starts with, you can press Ctrl+., and click "Convert to 'Program.Main' style program"
[image: example]

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I didn't know such a thing exists. :)

Comment: This is also valid for "conventional" VS editions.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a console application project on the command line, there are [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#console) you can specify.  By default:

```
dotnet new console
```

Will create a console application in the "newer" (as of .NET 6) style of allowing top-level statements.  You can suppress this on the command line when creating the project:

```
dotnet new console --use-program-main
```

This would create the project with an explicit class and method entry point.

Comment: Actually, I knew it from the link I provided in the question but since I find it easy to use Solution Explorer not CLI in VS Code Editor.  But thank you again.